# Pycurl Multi Max requests per sec

Tags: python, google-geocoding-api, pycurl

I am using below code to hit google geocoding api's to get longitude and latitude, but i need to hit max 50 api/sec. Is there any attribute to set value for no of api calls per sec in pycurl muti?

```
urls = [] # multiple urls
m = pycurl.CurlMulti()
for url in urls: 
    response = BytesIO()
    handle = pycurl.Curl()
    handle.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    handle.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, response.write)
    req = (url, response, handle)
    m.add_handle(req[2])
    reqs.append(req)


SELECT_TIMEOUT = 1.0
num_handles = len(reqs)
while num_handles:
    ret = m.select(SELECT_TIMEOUT)
    if ret == -1:
        continue
    while 1:
        ret, num_handles = m.perform()
    
        print(ret, num_handles)
        if ret != pycurl.E_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM: 
            break
count=1
lst = []
for req in reqs:
    lst.append(req[1].getvalue())# contains response content
```

Comment: No, you need to do that in your own application.

Comment: The geocoding service is rate limited to [50 QPS (queries per second)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/geocoding-strategies#rate-limits), calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries. You need to introduce random intervals to your requests (jitter). Ensure requests are random across your entire userbase.